# How to set default scale on a per bone basis

Tags: animation, skeletal-animation, maya, scale, bones

Does anyone know how I can change the default scale on a per bone basis in Maya? (I'm using 2016)

[image]

I want the scale to be 1,1,1 for this bone without making it smaller than it currently is.

So, I want to make the default scale of this bone 1.552, 1.552, 1.552.
Therefore, it would read 1,1,1 but still be the same size.

Does anyone know how to do this?